# Use WCF or Web API for a service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have the following environment setup (please see diagram below - open it in a new tab in case it's too small):

[image]

What I need to achieve is the following:

Add the new data (job ads that come in once or twice per day) from the old database to the new database.

Which service model should I use - WCF or Web API?

Comment: from which client you need to do this job ? web/mobile app/windows app etc.

Comment: Does the "Client" node represent you in the diagram?

Comment: That is part of the question actually.What type of client would be required for either WCF or Web API. The clients task will be to talk to WCF or Web API and then insert the data into the new database. So there is no GUI involved.

Comment: Your diagram shows Old DB --> Decision.  Does that mean the decision is in a database stored procedure, and the database will be calling the WCF/WebAPI service?  If so, what database is it?  If not, does that mean the service is polling the database?

Comment: @MobyDisk The "Decision" box in the diagram denotes which of the two technologies (WCF or Web API) I should use. There is no decisionmaking in the database. About the "polling" question. That is also something that I'm not really sure about wheather to "poll" the database, run a windows schedular task that runs every hour or having a trigger in the database?

Comment: In general: Use WebAPI over WCF.  Everything can call WebAPI: T-SQL, C#, Java, Javascript, ...  WCF is kinda on the way out.